# WordPress wp_email() is not accepting from value properly

Tags: wordpress

I am sending an email with `wp_mail()` function with the following **header** details but it's not sending email!

```
// get header details
$sn_header_name     =   !empty ( get_option( 'sn_header_name' ) ) ? get_option( 'sn_header_name' ) : get_bloginfo( 'name' );
$sn_header_email    =   !empty ( get_option( 'sn_header_email' ) ) ? get_option( 'sn_header_email' ) : get_bloginfo( 'admin_email' );

$headers = array(
    "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8",
    "From: {$sn_header_name} &lt;{$sn_header_email}&gt;"
);
```

Using the above **header details** `wp_mail()` is not working but if I remove this line:

```
"From: {$sn_header_name} &lt;{$sn_header_email}&gt;"
```

It's sending email properly.

can you tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

There maybe some special character or html tag in header name which stopping to send mail. Can you please try this

```
// get header details
$sn_header_name     =   !empty ( get_option( 'sn_header_name' ) ) ? get_option( 'sn_header_name' ) : get_bloginfo( 'name' );
$sn_header_email    =   !empty ( get_option( 'sn_header_email' ) ) ? get_option( 'sn_header_email' ) : get_bloginfo( 'admin_email' );
$sn_header_email= esc_attr($sn_header_email);
$sn_header_name = esc_attr($sn_header_name);
$headers = array(
    "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8",
    "From: {$sn_header_name} <{$sn_header_email}>"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to set it once and forget it, you can use these 2 hooks in your theme's **functions.php** :

**wp_mail_from** :

```
add_filter('wp_mail_from','custom_wp_mail_from');

function custom_wp_mail_from($original_email) {
  return 'mail@example.com';
}
```

**wp_mail_from_name** :

```
add_filter('wp_mail_from_name','custom_wp_mail_from_name');

function custom_wp_mail_from_name($original_name) {
  return 'John Doe';
}
```